# Make Image.asset have ripple effect on tap flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ripple-effect

I am trying to make my `Image.asset()` in Flutter have a ripple effect whenever the image is tapped

Below are my image assets

```
Image.asset('images/ic_close.png')
```

I have tried placing it inside `InkWell` and providing a splash color but it's also not working. Below is how I have tried to achieve a ripple effect using `InkWell`

```
InkWell(
  splashColor: Colors.black87,
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
  child: Image.asset('images/ic_close.png'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a ripple effect, you need to use the [`Ink.image`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink/Ink.image.html) constructor.

But The problem is that `Ink.image` doesn't have an `onTap`. so, let's create our own reusable widget that supports an `onTap`:

```dart
class CustomImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final Function() onTap;

  const CustomImage({super.key, required this.imageUrl, required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Ink.image(
      image: AssetImage(imageUrl),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: CustomImage(
              imageUrl: 'images/ic_close.png',
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          )
```

Comment: This is almost great - but it doesn't quite work for me - I have a background image for my page (achieved by having a Stack, and this button image is on top of the background image) - once I add the Ink widget, the button image gets put behind the background image for some reason (and is, thus, invisible).

Comment: OK - and the solution for my issue in the above comment was simply to wrap the `Ink` inside a `Material` widget : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63493362/1290746

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your Inkwell also with transparent Material widget. If your Image have no background, it will work like this (because you see it through its transparent parts):

```
 Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Image.asset('images/ic_close.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

If you want to overlay your full image, I only found a ways with stack. Like:

```
Stack(
            children: [
              Image.asset('images/ic_close.png'),
              Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50, // height of your image
                    width: 50, // width of your image
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```